# Thymeleaf conditional operator giving error as could not parse an expression

Tags: thymeleaf

I am new to Thyemleaf and facing the issue of could not parse an expression

```html
<p th:if="${modelMap.languages.size()&le; 2}" th:text="Items are less">Items
        are less
```

i want to print a certain message on screen when the value of the list is less than 2

i am getting the below message when i am running the code

---

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse
> as expression: "${modelMap.languages.size()} ≤ 2" (template: "profile"
> - line 32, col 5)    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:131)
> ~thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]   at
> org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:62)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]

Comment: You should provide some more info... are you using Spring MVC? How is the page loaded, is modelMap added as an attribute? Show page-snippet with the used expression... My guess is that you add a list of languages to your model; so the expression should be `${languages.size} ge 2`

Comment: @DirkDeyne Thanks for Replying, i have tried what u said but its still giving error

Comment: `code` @RequestMapping("/profile") public ModelAndView viewProfile() { List<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>(); languages.add("English"); languages.add("Hindi"); // languages.add("Marathi"); Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(); modelMap.put("name", "Mukul"); modelMap.put("age", 25); modelMap.put("address", "Pune"); modelMap.put("dateOfBirth", LocalDate.of(1997, 04, 17)); modelMap.put("languages", languages); // modelMap.put("", null); return new ModelAndView("profile", "modelMap", modelMap); }

Comment: Put code controller + sample html in your question. Edit your question.

Comment: Is my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Use `le` instead of `&le;`

So this should work:

```html
<p th:if="${modelMap.languages.size le 2}"> 2 or fewer languages </p>
<p th:if="${modelMap.languages.size ge 3}"> 3 or more languages </p>
```

Other expressions:

- `lt` = less then
- `le` = less than or equal
- `gt` = greater than
- `ge` = greater than or equals
- `eq` = equals
- `neq` = not equals

But you also can use `&gt;`, `&lt;`, `==`, `!=`